# How to send an enquiry command with DirectIO() in POS for .NET?

Tags: c#, barcode-scanner, pos-for-.net

I'm currently working on a project to control a Honeywell Genesis 7580G scanner using C#, POS for .NET and the POS4NET Suite from Honeywell. I would like to get the current serial read time-out, so I called the DirectIO() method from POS4NET in the following way:

```
string command = "TRGSTO?.";
DirectIOData response = scanner.DirectIO(18, 1024, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command));
byte[] buffer = (byte[])response.Object;
Console.WriteLine("$: Response: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer));
```

This code prints:

"$: Response: TRGSTO20"

which lacks three zeros (the time unit is milliseconds) and the [ACK] character. 
I was expecting this...

"$: Response: TRGSTO20000[ACK]"

However, if I change the command to get a different setting...

```
string command = "BEPPWR?.";
DirectIOData response = scanner.DirectIO(18, 1024, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command));
byte[] buffer = (byte[])response.Object;
Console.WriteLine("$: Response: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer));
```

The code works as expected, and prints

"$: Response: BEPPWR1[ACK]"

What is the correct way to send an enquiry command using DirectIO()?

Comment: `DirectIO` is specific for each device. You have to read its manual for details and examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that the response data may have arrived correctly and was converted as a character string so that it is considered to have ended with zero?

Please check the content of byte array data using `BitConverter.ToString()` instead of `Encoding.ASCII.GetString()`.

Comment: I investigated related specifications.
Looking at the item "Serial Trigger Mode : Read Time-Out" on page 162 of "Genesis 7580g User's Guide", the setting range is 0 to 300000, so it is a maximum of 6 digits, but the numerical parameter part of the command is 4 digits.
However, setting the same range of values "Hands Free Time-Out" on page 163, the numeric parameter part of the command is 6 digits.
For "Serial Trigger Mode : Read Time-Out", one of the document / service object / firmware may be incorrect.
Please check with the vendor what is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use POS for .NET with a fiscal printer POS. When i need to send a DirectIO i use this type of code in order to send and receive response: I hope it could be useful

```
string[] strObj = new string[1];
DirectIOData dirIO;
int iData;
strObj[0] = "01";
dirIO = posCommonFP.DirectIO(0, 1138, strObj);
iData = dirIO.Data;
strObj = (string[])dirIO.Object;
```